# Raising to the power of zero

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

As we know, raising any non-zero number to the power of zero gives `1`, since `n^0 = n^(a-a) = n^a / n^a = 1`.

I just noticed that JavaScript implementations (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari) will shortcut such operation, ignoring the first operand and returning `1`. However, these implementations don't simply ignore the first *numeric* operand, they completely ignore anything!

```js
console.log("hello" ** 0);
console.log(false ** 0);
console.log({} ** 0);
console.log(NaN ** 0);
console.log(null ** 0);
console.log(Infinity ** 0);
```

My question is: is that behavior an implementation (meaning it can change at any moment), or is it described by ECMA somewhere? I [searched ECMA](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-exp-operator) but I couldn't find anything

Comment: Are you sure they're *ignoring* the first operand, or merely casting it to a numeric value?

Comment: Interesting.  I just tried an experiment with `base() **  exp()`. Where both functions write to the console and base returns `"hello"` and exp returns `0`.  Guess what happened?  base ran first, laying waste to my short-circuit hypothesis (that upon finding a zero exponent, no further operands are evaluated).

Comment: I think what you'll find is that this is a combination of type coercion and `NaN ** 0 === 1`

Comment: Anyway, as a practical matter, if it seems fishy (as this does), and I can't get clarity that it's in the spec, I'd write defensive code around it.

Comment: @Megapteranovaeangliae I meant for the obvious non-number arguments. `Infinity` is a number

Answer (score 2):

The exponentiation operator **does not** ignore or short-circuit the base operand if the exponent is 0. However, the check for the exponent being equal to 0 happens early enough in the operator's algorithm that the edge cases are difficult to observe. To understand what is happening, it's necessary to consult the ECMAScript specification on what happens when the `**` operator is invoked:

> ### 13.6 Exponentiation Operator
>
> #### 13.6.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation
>
> *ExponentiationExpression* **:** *UpdateExpression*  ****** *ExponentiationExpression*
>
> 1. Return ? EvaluateStringOrNumericBinaryExpression(*UpdateExpression*, ******,
>    *ExponentiationExpression*).

The abstract operation EvaluateStringOrNumericBinaryExpression **evaluates both operands** and passes them to another abstract operation:

> #### 13.15.4 EvaluateStringOrNumericBinaryExpression (leftOperand, opText, rightOperand)
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *leftOperand*.
> 2. Let *lval* be ? GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *rightOperand*.
> 4. Let *rval* be ? GetValue(*rref*).
> 5. Return ? ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator(*lval*, *opText*, *rval*).

The abstract operation ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator takes a binary operator together with its operands, **performs the required type coercion** and calls the abstract operation associated with the operator:

> #### 13.15.3 ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator (lval, opText, rval)
>
> 1. If *opText* is `+`, then [...]
> 2. NOTE: At this point, it must be a numeric operation.
> 3. **Let *lnum* be ? ToNumeric(*lval*).**
> 4. Let *rnum* be ? ToNumeric(*rval*).
> 5. [...]
> 6. [...]
> 7. Let *operation* be the abstract operation associated with *opText* and Type(*lnum*) in the following table: [...]
> 8. Return operation(*lnum*, *rnum*).

It is at this point that the base operand is converted to a number. `"hello"` and `{}` become `NaN`, `false` and `null` become `0`, numbers remain numbers, BigInts remain BigInts. Finally, if *opText* is `**` and Type(*lnum*) is Number, the associated operation is Number::exponentiate:

> #### 6.1.6.1.3 Number::exponentiate (base, exponent)
>
> 1. If *exponent* is NaN, return NaN.
> 2. **If *exponent* is +0 or exponent is -0, return 1**.

It would thus seem that no matter what the base operand is, if the exponent is 0, the `**` operator always returns 1. It would, if it wasn't for step 3 of ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator. ToNumeric throws a TypeError if the argument is of type Symbol:

```
> Symbol() ** 0
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a number
```

This goes to show that raising something to the power of zero does not ignore the base operand.

Comment: "*edge cases are difficult to observe*" - `({[Symbol.toPrimitive](t) { console.log('coerced to '+t); return 1}}) ** 0`